How to draw line on 3D object in Blender?
I want to draw lines on a 3D character's eyes, but when I try, they appear as dots instead of continuous lines. Also, I didn’t enable the symmetry option, but it still seems to work like a mirror mode. How can I fix these issues?
I'm using v4.3.2
I add my brush settings






Please show your brush settings (with the mouse cursor over the 3D Viewport, press N, and make sure the appearing sidebar is on the Tool tab).

Maybe you've enabled a texture mask (under Texture in the N panel)?

And please ask separate questions as separate questions.

please pack your images and share your file

@TheLabCat I add my brush setting image!

@moonboots I'm not sure that I enabled a texture mask TT so I upload my texture mask capture image. could you check plz?

Could you please pack your images and share your file?

I'm afraid that there is no feature of uploading file..
I posted my image file.. but Isn't that what you're looking for?

Try to upload on a site like workupload and share the link here
